# Submit Dynamically Created Form using Button Outside The Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a page that can add more than one invoice in a page. There is a link, to display invoice fields in modal form. This form is dynamically created using ajax.

After filling out the invoice fields, I want to submit the form by button in the modal footer. This button is not generated dynamically, only form in the modal body.

How to submit the invoice fields in modal form using button that is outside the modal form?

Here is the code

**Create Invoice View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Invoice", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div id="invoiceList">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_InvoiceList", Model.Invoices); }
        </div>

        <a href="#" id="lnkAddInvoice">Add Row..</a>
        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="modal fade" id="addInvoiceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Invoice</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="add-invoice-container">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveInvoice">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#lnkAddInvoice").click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Content("~/Invoice/AddInvoice")",
                cache: false
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (!data.message) {
                    $("#add-invoice-container").html(data);
                    $("#addInvoiceModal").modal({ show: true, backdrop: true });
                } else {
                    $("#addInvoiceModal").modal("hide");
                }
            });
        });

        $("#btnSaveInvoice").click(function (e) {
            // Submit frmInvoice in modal form ???
        });
    });
</script>
```

**AddInvoice (Modal)**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddInvoice", "Invoice", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmInvoice" }))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i got understood the question correct, but if you only have the button outside the form you could do something like this.

```
 $("#btnSaveInvoice").click(function (e) {
     var $frm  = $("#frmInvoice");
     if($frm.length > 0){
        $frm.submit()
     }
 });
```

[Form submit jquery](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: As you can see in the code above, `btnSaveInvoice` is outside `frmInvoice` and `frmInvoice` is generated dynamically. I think when we deal with dynamic html we should use `$(document).???` I don't know the syntax. I just want to submit the `frmInvoice` that is generated dynamically

Comment: @Willy in this case you really don't because as long as the button is there at the start it doesn't matter, you maybe just should check if the form is null in case the user presses the button before the form is rendered, i'll update my answer.

Comment: @Willy as a small thing in you're UI you `btnSaveInvoice` the in the js you use `btnAddInvoice` for the selector

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 you can use the `form` attribute to specify a button that is outside the `<form>` tags is associated with the form

```
<form id="myForm" .....> // give the form an ID
    ....
</form>
<button type="submit" form="myForm" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Note: It seems that this may not yet be supported in IE

Comment: I'm using IE 11, as you already noted, it doesn't work with IE

Comment: No the best source, but [this confirmed my suspicions](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but most of the users still use IE as the browser.